# 4 layer stackup Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-layers

Can someone explain to me how I can change the layout order of my 4 layer board in eagle.

I'm sure this is really a silly question, I'm coming from Kicad so I'm a bit green here.

It's not obvious to me how I would do this

Currently its (1+2*15+16)

Layer 1- GND ||
Layer 2 - Signal 1 ||
Layer 3 - Signal 2 ||
Layer 4 - VCC

But what I need is

Layer 1- Signal 1 ||
Layer 2 - GND ||
Layer 3 - VCC ||
Layer 4 - Signal 2

I'm sure its something simple, but not clear how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: If you type `drc` and go to the `Layers` tab, you can see the set up for the layers. However you really don't need to identify them as signal/gnd/vcc, etc. The inner layers will be named "Route N" where "N" is the layer number.

Comment: I'm not familair with Eagle, but with Altium and KiCAD, the program produces a separate Gerber file for each layer.  You have to tell the PCB shop in what order you want those files used to create your PCB.  I always included a readme.txt file with my PCB orders detailing the layer order, drill sizes and overall board size, and any other special instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eagle doesn't have a concept of specific purposes for copper layers beyond top and bottom being used for component placement.

Your layer string is fine for what you need. `(1+2*15+16)` creates a four-layer board with no blind or buried vias.

You will get in Eagle the four routing layers, 1, 2, 15, and 16, which are all simply copper layers that you can use for any purpose.

If you want to use the inner layers for VCC and GND, simply draw polygons on layers 2 and 15 and name them for the appropriate net.

Comment: thanks for that. I'm so used to kicad that it just didnt make sense. I was able to do it now. Thank you